# Child born to Portugese and Indian parents in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, indian-citizens, children, portuguese-citizens

How to obtain a visa for a child born in the UK to Portuguese and Indian parents so to facilitate them to return to India and re-enter the UK?

Comment: What citizenship(s) does the child have?  (For example, whether the child is a British citizen depends on whether at least one parent is "settled" in the UK.)  Are you asking about entry requirements for both India and the UK, or only about one of them?

Answer (score 1):

If you can establish the child is a Portugal citizen (I don't know Portugal's rules on this) then they won't need a visa as they are an EU citizen.

Alternatively, they can enter the UK as the dependent family member of an EU citizen. You'll need to prove that with a birth certificate.

Comment: It's also possible that the child is a British citizen.

Comment: @phoog The child cannot be British because both the parents are not British. If one of the parent is an illegal immigrant, then its a different matter altogether.

Comment: @phoog could you expand? I think that arises if at least one parent has settled status in the UK. I did think the asker would resolve the matter for themselves once they get the baby a passport to put the visa in.

Comment: @TheLastWord that's not how it works. If one parent has settled status, the child is British, regardless of the other parent's status, even if the other parent is in the country illegally. It's not necessary for a parent to be British.

Comment: User16259: there's not much to expand; I was just mentioning the possibility. If the child is British, I suppose the visa should be refused and the parents encouraged to get a UK passport for the child.

Comment: @phoog From what I read on the UK home office website, at least one of the parents need to be British. This system used to exist but was taken out years ago. Please link to a credible page of the home office to substantiate ur claim.

Comment: @TheLastWord see https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen/y/on-or-after-1-january-1983/yes/yes, where one qualifying question is "When you were born, was one of your parents a British citizen *or legally settled in the UK?"* (emphasis added).

Comment: @TheLastWord what did you read on the home office site? Can you link to it?

Comment: @phoog Your right about the legally settled bit but I think that would mean an ILR https://www.gov.uk/types-of-british-nationality/british-citizenship . I stand corrected.  How does one get to enter UK freely or work without any restriction without an ILR or being a permanent resident.

Comment: @TheLastWord there are all manner of work visas for non-EU workers in the UK, but in this case (as a Portuguese national) there is EU freedom of movement.  Furthermore, ILR is not the only settled status; permanent residence under EU law also counts.  So if the Portuguese parent lived in the UK longer than 5 years before the child's birth, the child is a British citizen.

Comment: @phoog are you sure? Cause I heard citizenship in UK comes with blood not soil. You meant every baby born in UK is automatically a UK citizen?

Comment: @Zich no, but every baby born in the UK of parents who are "settled" is indeed a UK citizen. See https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-born-uk ("You’re automatically a British citizen if you were both: •born in the UK on or after 1 January 1983 •born when one of your parents was a British citizen or ‘settled’ in the UK").

Comment: @phoog Thanks for clarification, does settlement include tier 2 visa? I mean is it applicable to a baby born in UK from parents on tier 2 visa ?

Comment: @Zich no.  It's on the page I linked to.  "Settled" means indefinite leave to remain, indefinite leave to enter, or permanent residence under EU law.  It presumably will also include the planned post-Brexit "settled status."